# Getting AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_html'?

Tags: python, html-table

My code looks something like this where i am trying to make a table of column "Supplier" and "Discount"

```
Discount_By_Suppliers = data.groupby(["Supplier"])["Discount"].sum()
Top_20_suppliers = Discount_By_Suppliers.nlargest(25)
print(Top_20_suppliers)
Top_20_suppliers.to_html('index.html')
```

what i am doing wrong? please help.

Comment: to_html works on Dataframe maybe you should try pd.Dataframe(Top_20_suppliers).to_html("index.html")

Comment: Thanks. I did something like this and it works for me. Top_20_suppliers = Top_20_suppliers.reset_index() after resetting index of dataFrame i am able to convert data into html file.

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this and see that it has not been "answered". As @dimension said, convert to a DataFrame and then .to_html() will will work.

```
Top_20_suppliers = pd.DataFrame(Top_20_suppliers)
Top_20_suppliers.to_html('index.html')
```